# How to do a SOQL left join

Tags: soql, joined-reports

I got these tables in SF    and listed a few fields below :

SF_Opportunity (dimension)

1. ID (Opportunity ID)
2. TXC_Converge__c
3. AB2__ABOrderID__c

SF_OpportunityLineItem (dimension)

1. ID (Line Item Opportunity ID)
2. OpportunityID
3. AB2__ABDropID__c (Ad Book Drop ID)
4. External_AdServer_ID__c

SF_Opportunity_Line_Item_Detail__c (fact)

1. ID (Line Item Detail ID)
2. Opportunity__c (Opportunity ID)
3. Opportunity_Line_Item_ID__c (Line Item Opportunity ID)
4. Drop_ID__c (Ad Book Drop ID)
5. Details_Start_Date__c (Date of Data)

Im  trying to do a left outer join between  SF_Opportunity_Line_Item_Detail__c  and  SF_OpportunityLineItem to bring   ID, Drop_ID_c  (from SF_Opportunity_Line_Item_Detail__c  ) and corresponding  External_AdServer_ID__c  ( from SF_OpportunityLineItem)

I was trying something like below and the same is not working. Any help?

SELECT ID,Drop_ID__c
(SELECT  External_AdServer_ID__c  FROM opportunityLineItem)
FROM Opportunity_Line_Item_Detail__c

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

SELECT ID, (SELECT External_AdServer_ID__c FROM opportunityLineItems),(SELECT ID,Drop_ID__c FROM Opportunity_Line_Item_Details__r)From Opportunity

you can use this also:

SELECT External_AdServer_ID__c, (SELECT Id,Drop_ID__c FROM Opportunity_Line_Item_Details__r) FROM opportunityLineItem

Comment: Hey Thanks.  Just to know. Do we need to include Opportunity table to achieve this.  Sorry if Im sounding naive

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that throws the below error.  

Error Code: INVALID_TYPE; Message: (SELECT Id,Drop_ID__c FROM Opportunity_Line_Item_Details__r) ^ ERROR at Row:2:Column:28 Didn't understand relationship 'Opportunity_Line_Item_Details__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.; <br/>